# Algorithm for generating the power set of a Set

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you are given a set, $S$, with cardinality 3. Describe a procedure (an algorithm) for generating $\mathcal P(S)$, the power set of $S$. How will you specify which element to select?

Comment: Wrong site? Perhaps *Math.Stackexchange* or *Stackoverflow* is what you're after?

Comment: @ciao The "algorithm" in *Mathematica* is `Subsets[S]`! :)

Comment: @MichaelE2: The code golf solution, eh?

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is empty, then its power set is $\mathcal P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$.

Otherwise, if $S$ is not empty, pick $s\in S$, let $S'=S\setminus \{s\}$, recursively compute $T=\mathcal P(S')$. Then $\mathcal P(S)=T\cup\{\,a\cup\{s\}:a\in T\,\}$

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all numbers from $0$ to $2^{|S|}-1$, and let the $n$-th bit stand for inclusion of the $n$-th item in the subset.

Comment: ... to $2^{|S|}-1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thanks -- I had that in mind but somehow I didn't write it :-)